# C++ - Ensuring Hard Disk (Drive) Is Not Idle During Program Execution

Tags: c++, windows, hard-drive, python-idle

I have a few questions:

1. Will the following C++ code ever cause my hard disk to idle after a certain amount of time has passed?

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main()
   {
       while(1);
   }
   ```
2. If so what can I add to this code to ensure that my hard disk will not idle during execution?
3. Is there anyway to check whether my hard disk is in an idle state, though C++ code?

Note: I am using Windows 7

Comment: Could you define idle.  I think you mean it in terms of A. not spinning at all, right?  Another use of idle means B. "running but doing nothing useful," i.e., a car idles while the engine is on, but not in motion--the engine is running, but no motion is achieved.  Do you mean A or B?  And regardless, you intend your question only with respect to your program, right?  I.e. you cannot control whether the OS or some other program might not run your hard drive anyway.

Answer (score 3):

1. If idle is enabled, yes, as it doesn't access the hard drive.
2. Nothing; your code might not even run from a hard drive. Even if you add code to read some data, it might be cached and not touch the disk. You can probably do something with writes followed by flushes, to ensure that data is committed to disk, but this will block your program during the flush (and this method is not reliable either.)
3. Could be that you can check using SMART or so, but remember, your program might not be running off a hard drive -- could be on an SSD, could be over network, could be from a RAM disk.

In general, you shouldn't include assumptions like this into your program. If you need to touch the disk and you are concerned that the hard drive might turn off and take a long time, ask the user to disable hard drive sleep. For server applications, this will be most likely a non-issue anyway as the drive is always running. For SSDs and stuff, it's a no-issue anyway, as those drives don't "spin up" from idle.

Comment: I wanted to add that supposing no other program using the hard drive is currently running this program will cause the hard disk to fall into an idle state after the time which you have set (if you have set one) for the driver to idle through `power management`.

Comment: Also about number 2, I am not quite so sure this is the correct answer, there might be a function not-so well known in the windows API or some other API used to manually set the timer of the disk_idle to zero -thus resulting in a disk never set in idle state-.

Comment: Right, there might be some power management API call, but this is nothing I would recommend calling. First of all, it probably needs administrative rights, and second, a group policy might override anything you set locally.